# Personalizando telas de Custom Post Type do Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou trabalhando em um template e plugin de classificados para um projeto (pois o cliente tem necessidades de campos que outros plugins não fornecem), entretanto não consigo inserir campos personalizados na postagem e na tela do exibição do post, para uma galeria de imagens ou campo de preço, por exemplo.
Gostaria de saber como posso inserir *custom fields* em *custom post types* e como
exibi-los na tela do post.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você queria mais "difícil". Você pode criar isso na mão.

Tem esse [gerador aqui](https://metabox.io/online-generator/) que pode te ajudar.

Se quiser algo mais simples alguns plugins que podem te ajudar.

O [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) e o [Meta Box](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/).

Segue a documentação que não tem erro.